# IEEE Tran - Making Centred Title page?

Tags: ieeetran

Currently making a lab report that is required to be in IEEE format except it also needs a coverpage per the professor's instructions. If I try to make a title page using \begin{titlepage} and then \maketitle it ends up taking 2 whole pages, one of them being blank and the other having only the title at the top.

Comment: I think the `\title` in IEEE is coded to work in a two-column page. Just put some ad hoc boxes in the middle of the cover page.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of like this?  Note, you could copy `\maketitle` or `\titlepage` from some other document class, or you could just format the page and not worry about restrictions or conventions.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\thispagestyle{empty}\setcounter{page}{0}%
Top of page
\hrule
\vfill
{\centering\Huge Middle of Page\par}
\vfill
Bottom of Page
\twocolumn
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```